# How do I automatically create content after checking out a product?

Tags: 7, nodes, ubercart, commerce

Is there a way or any module out there that would enable me to automatically create content after checking out a certain product?

Comment: Did you try [Rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules)?

Comment: @Topsitemakers Thank you for your suggestion. I'll go check it out.

Comment: Seems you asked the same question twice. It is not OK. If your original question does not give you your answer, it means it is probably unclear, too broad, or looks like "do my work for me" thing. Improve, don't re-ask. Not to mention that both appears to be duplicates of older, already answered one - that's different. It is OK to ask a question that turns out to be a duplicate of a question you didn't know about, after all search isn't perfect.